# Is it possible to sum iterators?

Tags: python, iterator, sum

For example, I have the following code:

```
def functionx(n):
    i = 0
    while i < 3:
        n += 2
        yield n
        i += 1



for i in functionx(x):
    op2 = i

for m in functionx(y):
    op1 = m
```

And then sum `op2` and `op1`, for example, but with the first yield, then do same for the second until `i` hits 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip). It does what exactly you are looking for. It iterates over both the iterators simultaneously, but lazily.

```
from itertools import izip

for i, m in izip(functionx(x), functionx(y)):
     print i + m
```

The difference between `zip` and `itertools.izip` in Python 2.x is

```
def functionx(n):
    i = 0
    while i < 3:
        n += 2
        print n
        yield n
        i += 1
```

Using `zip`,

```
for i, m in zip(functionx(3), functionx(3)):
    print "Sum", i + m
```

**Output**

```
5
5
7
7
9
9
Sum 10
Sum 14
Sum 18
```

Using `itertools.izip`,

from itertools import izip
for i, m in izip(functionx(3), functionx(3)):
    print "Sum", i + m

**Output**

```
5
5
Sum 10
7
7
Sum 14
9
9
Sum 18
```

As you can see, `itertools.izip` iterates only on demand.

**Note:** In Python 3.x, there is no `izip`, the default behavior of `zip` itself is similar to that of `izip`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i,m in zip(functionx(x), functionx(y)):
    result = i + m
```

**Edit:** Aaron Hall makes a good point - if one generated sequence is longer than the other, you might want to

```
# from itertools import izip_longest as zl    # Python 2.x
from itertools import zip_longest as zl     # Python 3.x

for i,m in zl(functionx(x), functionx(y), fillvalue=0):
    result = i + m
```

Comment: Maybe should use the zip longest?